# Adding data from ngModel to firebase

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, firebase

I am trying to add data from user input to firebase, however it is not working. This is my input field:

```
<div class="bed-price cc">
                <label for="name" class="subtitle-secondary">Name</label>
                <input *ngIf="pePropertyStep" type="text" name="name" class="minimal_input shadow_xlight"
                       [(ngModel)]="pePropertyStep.mid_tenants.mid_tenant_name"  #name="ngModel" placeholder="Name">
              </div>
```

This is the model:

```
export interface PropertyPropertyModel {
  description: string;
  lease_type: string;
  is_mid_tenancy: boolean;
  mid_tenants: Array<{ mid_tenant_name: string, mid_tenant_email: string, mid_tenant_rent_price: number, status: string}>;
}
```

and how I am initialising it:

```
initPropertyProperty = (): PropertyPropertyModel => {
    return {
      description: '',
      is_mid_tenancy: false,
      mid_tenants: [
        { mid_tenant_name: '', mid_tenant_email: '', mid_tenant_rent_price: 0, status: 'pending'}
      ],
}
```

and populating it:

```
populatePropertyProperty = (property: PropertyModel): PropertyPropertyModel => {
    return {
      description: property.description,
      is_mid_tenancy: property.is_mid_tenancy,
      mid_tenants: property.mid_tenants,
}
```

However, before I can even try and push to firebase, I receive this error in the console:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'mid_tenant_name' of undefined
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (PeInfoPropertyComponent.html:19)
```

which Is the html section above. I have used this exact methods for other forms of uploading to firebase and it has worked perfectly. Is it something to do with the fact that I am creating an array of objects?

Comment: I think it's complaining because you have tried to use a variable "name" in the html, but it's not defined in the component. You need to define "name" or rename it to be the property you care about. The code causing the issue:  #name="ngModel"

Comment: Removed it and still have the same error @LukeBecker

Comment: The error you're getting is because of `[(ngModel)]="pePropertyStep.mid_tenants.mid_tenant_name"`. `pePropertyStep.mid_tenants` is clearly undefined, so it can't bind to a property of an undefined object. Try changing your ngIf to `*ngIf="pePropertyStep && pePropertyStep.mid_tenants"`.

Comment: I think I see the issue now. Your mid_tenants property is an array. It will need to be accessed by index. Example: mid_tenants[0].mid_tenant_name. Or put it in an ngFor loop. https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf

Comment: @JosephWebber Error has gone, but so has the input field..

Comment: @Jm3s see my previous answer. This is the reason the input field disappeared. There is no mid_tenant_name on the property mid_tenants because mid_tenants is an array of objects.

Comment: I didn't notice `mid_tenants` is an array, sorry. you'll have to do what Luke said in his comment. As a side question, why is `mid_tenants` an array if it only contains one object? If it's going to contain multiple objects, how will it know which one to bind to? `mid_tenants[0]` is always going to bind to the first one, regardless of how many it contains.

Comment: @JosephWebber I am going to add multiple through this method

Comment: @Jm3s You will need to use the *ngFor method that I mentioned above to list multiple tenants and bind them.

Comment: @LukeBecker I have added: 

  <div class="bed-price cc" *ngFor="let tenant of pePropertyStep.mid_tenants">
                  <label for="name" class="subtitle-secondary">Name</label>
                  <input *ngIf="pePropertyStep && tenant" type="text" name="name" class="minimal_input shadow_xlight"
                         [(ngModel)]="tenant.mid_tenant_name"  placeholder="Name">
                </div>

Comment: but it returns this: Cannot read property 'mid_tenants' of undefined on the ngFor

Answer (score 0):

It's because property `mid_tenants` is defined as an array in your model and you're accessing it incorrectly
Specify an array position in order to access the object
example

```
 [(ngModel)]="pePropertyStep.mid_tenants[0].mid_tenant_name"
```